# How to call setForegroundAsync for a chain of workers

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm migrating some legacy code, that used to be executed with a ForegroundService, to be executed using WorkManager. I have 3 workers that I set to execute sequentially. What I can't understand is how to set the foreground notification when I have separate workers. What if I have parallel worker execution by using continuation? Do I call setForegroundAsync for each worker? I really need clarification on this.

Comment: Why do you need to implement these three different workers?
How it was the original implementation with the ForegroundService?

Comment: There is a common step for initialization and two other workers use the output from the initialization

Comment: If none of these steps is going to take more than 10 minutes you can avoid to promote the Workers to Foreground Services and simply show a notification if needed. Or you can limit the use of a Foreground Service only for the workers that may need more than 10 minutes. There's an article that covers this topic: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-workmanager-for-immediate-background-execution-a57db502603d